# Read a csv file, insert newly calculated values in rows/cells and overwrite the same csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv, insert, append

I want to read a csv file called Books.csv which contains multiple rows and insert new rows after row number 19. Each row value is limited to its first cell (A1 to A24).

I have calculated/iterated a string called "c" consisting of 30 rows.

```
import csv

variant = "VC4"
MET = "cutting.MET"
name = "Rob"
Base_ModQual = -0.8
Deg_rate = 0.30
Num_Years = 30


for i in range(Num_Years+1):
    deg = (Base_ModQual + (i)*Deg_Rate)
    c = ("SIM_" + str(i+2) + ";" + variant + ";" + MET + ";" + name + "_Year" + str(i) + "_" + f'{deg:.2f}' + "%modrate.csv" +";" + f'{deg:.2f}' +";")
    print(c)
```

**TASK:** to insert string "c" in the csv file from row 20 (cell A20) to row 50 (cell A50) such that original A20-A24 cells shifts to A51-A55 cells respectively.

```
with open('Books.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('Books.csv', 'a') as write_file:
       reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter =";")
       j = 0
       for row in reader: 
          if j < row[19]:
             row.append(c)               
             print(row)
```

I am unable to insert new rows and overwrite books.csv with new data.

**Edit:** Here is the screenshot of the Books.csv file. I want to insert contents in from A20 onwards.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible to read and append at the same time, but your file doesn't seem to be big, so maybe first read it's content and append the new rows and save afterwards?

**Edit**

Thanks for the screenshot. Seems like `;` is not the column delimiter, because the values inside the cells also contains `;`. The delimiter is probably `,`, but I don't think it matters, because -- if I understood you right -- you just want to keep the rows *as they are*. So there is no need for a `csv.reader`, just read the lines in plain text with `readlines()`, e.g.:

```
import csv

variant = "VC4"
MET = "cutting.MET"
name = "Rob"
Base_ModQual = -0.8
Deg_rate = 0.30
Num_Years = 30

INSERT_ROW = 20

new_content = []
with open('Books.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    #reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter =',')
    reader = csv_file.readlines()
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == INSERT_ROW:
            for i in range(Num_Years+1):
                deg = (Base_ModQual + (i)*Deg_rate)
                c = ("SIM_" + str(i+2) + ";" + variant + ";" + MET + ";" + name + "_Year" + str(i) + "_" + f'{deg:.2f}' + "%modrate.csv" +";" + f'{deg:.2f}' +";")
                new_content.append(c + '\n')
        else:
            new_content.append(row)

with open('Books.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    for line in new_content:
        csv_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to read first and then append the new rows. I am getting the following error on the last line       csv_file.write(line[0] + '\n')                                                                     
        "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: try without the `[0]`, so `csv_file.write(line + '\n') `. Or can you provide me a sample of your Books.csv file, mybe first 3 rows?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the books.csv file in the original comment. `csv_file.write(line + '\n')`  got error of `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: I edited my post, could you give the new solution a  try? :-)

Comment: Thanks. I got error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list` in the last line. I changed the last line to get output by changing it to `csv_file.write(str(line))`          However, the output file didnt keep the top rows (A1-A19) as is it was in the original file Books.csv

Comment: Are you sure, that you replaced the whole code, not just the last line? I also made some modefications before.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine! Thanks a ton ilja! using `.readlines()` worked as compared to the `csv.reader` method. Also, I read that `readlines()` returns a list as a result, your last line worked `csv_file.write(line)` without converting it into string. The only downside to ReadLines() is that it will attempt to read the entire file all at once, which works here as it is a small file size. When do we use readlines() vs csv.reader(..) ?

Comment: Thanks marc_s! So we use `readlines()` method when we are reading whole file vs `csv.reader()` is used when we read only few rows?

Comment: I'm not sure, if there is a significant performance difference between `readlines()` and `csv.reader()`, but `readlines()` is more practical in your case, because it keeps the rows as strings (you dont really need columns of the csv) on import, so you can just use this *raw* data to store it again in a file, On the other hand, `csv.reader()` would split the string in a list of strings (based on csv-delimiter-columns) and you would have to convert it back to a single string before saving (would theoretically also work with some more code)